# GroupBy without LINQ

Tags: c#

I am trying to achieve the following without LINQ:

I have a list of CenterDetail objects (with CenterID and AreaID as property):

- objCenterDetail1 (CenterID=1, AreaID=1)
- objCenterDetail2 (CenterID=2, AreaID=1)
- objCenterDetail3 (CenterID=3, AreaID=1)
- objCenterDetail4 (CenterID=5, AreaID=2)
- objCenterDetail5 (CenterID=6, AreaID=2)

I want to create an AreasDictionary as follows:

- AreaID=1: objCenterDetail1, objCenterDetail2, objCenterDetail3
- AreaID=2: objCenterDetail4, objCenterDetail5

What is the best solution for this in C# with .NET 2.0?

Comment: ...wha? You might want to consider a better example because, as of now, this question makes no sense.

Comment: You could use LINQ in .NET 2.0: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, List<CenterDetail>> map = new Dictionary<int, List<CenterDetail>>();
foreach (CenterDetail detail in details)
{
    List<CenterDetail> list;
    if (!map.TryGetValue(detail.AreaID, out list)
    {
        list = new List<CenterDetail>();
        map.Add(detail.AreaID, list);
    }
    list.Add(detail);
}
return map;
```

Comment: Since the poster mentioned .NET 2.0, just be sure that you replace the var statements in the above example with the actual types.

Comment: @Ben - Opps. Force of habit I guess.

Comment: `var` works with .NET 2.0 as target platform - if you use the .NET 3.5 compiler ;-)

Comment: Man, without `var` the type noise is nauseating.

Answer (score 1):

Not using LINQ typically means using foreach to iterate over your collection instead:

```
IEnumerable<Center> centers = // Assume this is your collection;
Dictionary<Area,List<Center>> areasDictionary = new Dictionary<Area,List<Center>>();
foreach(Center center in centers) 
{
    if (!areasDictionary.ContainsKey(center.Area) ) 
        areasDictionary.Add(center.Area, new List<Center>());
    areasDictionary[center.Area].Add(center);
}
```

Now this probably won't compile in your solution since you haven't given us enough information about the particular types involved, but it does demonstrate the general idea.